# Operator overloading << in C++

Tags: c++, io, operator-overloading

I wrote this simple program to practice overloading.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class sex_t
{
    private:
        char __sex__;

    public:
        sex_t(char sex_v = 'M'):__sex__(sex_v)
        {
            if (sex_v != 'M' && sex_v != 'F')
            {
                cerr << "Sex type error!" << sex_v << endl;
                __sex__ = 'M';
            }
        }

        const ostream& operator << (const ostream& stream)
        {
            if (__sex__ == 'M')
                cout << "Male";
            else
                cout << "Female";
            return stream;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sex_t me('M');
    cout << me << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it, it print lots of error messages:

The error message was in a mess.

It's too hard for me to found a useful message.

```
sex.cpp: 在函数‘int main(int, char**)’中:
sex.cpp:32:10: 错误： ‘operator<<’在‘std::cout << me’中没有匹配
sex.cpp:32:10: 附注： 备选是：
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:110:7: 附注： std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostre
```

Comment: `cerr << "Sex type error!" << sex_v` You're right, I've never heard of that position.

Comment: In all seriousness, one thing you should definitely NOT do is use two leading underscores. That is reserved for the implementation.

Comment: what should I do? use `_sex_` OR other?

Comment: Some common ones for class members are `m_sex`, `_sex`, `sex_`, or just `sex`, depending on what you name your function parameters.

Comment: Say, don't you regret not naming the sole member variable `gender` instead of `sex`?

Comment: I think `m_chSex` or `m_chGender` is ok

Comment: Sex, streams, `friend`s accessing `private` members... Either I am just discovering unintentional innuendo or Stroustrup is a pervert.

Comment: @thlgood: SO's [C++ FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) has [an answer for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When overloading for streams, you declare a << operator globally and/or as a `friend` (with benefits) to your class so it can access its 'private members' (ooh...). You can declare a `friend` inside the class to declare it globally. Do not use `const` on the streams.

Next, use the passed stream in your overload. In your method, you use `cout` when you would have used it anyway by just using the `stream` argument.

I have not tested this, but see if it works for you.

```
class sex_t
{
private:
    char __sex__;
public:
    sex_t(char sex_v = 'M'):__sex__(sex_v)
    {
        if (sex_v != 'M' && sex_v != 'F')
        {
            cerr << "Sex type error!" << sex_v << endl;
            __sex__ = 'M';
        }
    }

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& stream, sex_t& sex);
};


ostream& operator << (ostream& stream, sex_t& sex)
{
    if (__sex__ == 'M')
        stream << "Male";
    else
        stream << "Female";
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: which is better? a friend `operator <<` or defining a `getSex()` function in `sex_t`?

Comment: @shengy, An `operator<<` is ideal if a user would expect to be able to print it.

Comment: @chris I mean a `friend operator<<` function or a `non-friend operator<<` function:)

Comment: @shengy, Ah, typically if you can provide a non-friend method, it's better, as it gives the least amount of privilege to the function.

Comment: @shengy - I would use a normal `operator <<` and use `getSex()` in it.

Comment: `__sex__` is [reserved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/) for the implementation.

Answer (score 4):

The argument and return from `operator<<` are non-const. Also it needs to be a non-member- you have written an overload for `me << cout`, not `cout << me`. Also, identifiers leading with two underscores are reserved for the implementation and using them is Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

"C++ Primer 4th Edition" Chapter 14 section 14.2 Input and Output Operators:

IO Operators Must Be Nonmember Functions, We cannot make the operator a member of our own class. If we did, then the left-hand operand would have to be an object of our class type:

```
// if operator<< is a member of Sales_item
     Sales_item item;
     item << cout;
```

The general skeleton of an overloaded output operator is

```
   // general skeleton of the overloaded output operator
     ostream&
     operator <<(ostream& os, const ClassType &object)
     {
         // any special logic to prepare object

         // actual output of members
         os << // ...

         // return ostream object
         return os;
     }
```

The first parameter is a reference to an ostream object on which the output will be generated. The ostream is nonconst because writing to the stream changes its state. The parameter is a reference because we cannot copy an ostream object.

The second parameter ordinarily should be a const reference to the class type we want to print. The parameter is a reference to avoid copying the argument. It can be const because (ordinarily) printing an object should not change it. By making the parameter a const reference, we can use a single definition to print const and nonconst objects.

The return type is an ostream reference. Its value is usually the ostream object against which the output operator is applied.

**EDIT**:

I tried to modify your code, and if you use `__sex__` as `sex_t`'s private member, you should write another `get function` to get the 'M' or 'F', and if you call it in your `operator<<` function, you will probably get an error, because a const reference could only call a const function, so you should make your `get function` a const function, just for reminde:)

Comment: Another advantage of using a *const* reference is that you can do something like this: `std::cout << sex_t('M');`, which cannot bind to a non-const reference.

Comment: @chris Yes:) I nearly forgot that